# SQL Server Memory-Optimized Tables - Change Primary Key Data Type

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to change an in-memory table column type from INT to BIGINT on SQL Server 2017. Actually, this column are the PK from table.

For a regular table, the common path is to drop the PK constraint, change the data type and recreate PK, but when I've tried in my in-memory table I got the following error:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.InMemTbl
   DROP CONSTRAINT PK_InMemTbl
```

> The memory optimized table 'InMemTbl' with DURABILITY=SCHEMA_AND_DATA
> must have a primary key

I'm not an expert in memory-optimized tables so is there any workaround to solve it without recreate the whole table using the new data type?

Comment: Short answer: no. And for a large regular table this approach isn't good either, if the PK is also the clustered index (the common scenario), since it involves rewriting the table no less than three times -- once to make it a heap, once to change the type and once more to build the clustered index. Building a new table is almost certainly a better idea there as well, with some added work for synchronizing changes.

Comment: Got it @JeroenMostert. Thanks a lot :=)